# Formatter function change array of objects structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I was facing this type of problems what is the best method to solve it. I was using map and reduce but without any results. Thanks in advance.

Giving this Array INPUT with this structure. Example:

```
[
{ 'id': 1, 'question_name': "What is your name?", 'question_value': "Jack"},
{ 'id': 2, 'question_name': "What is your hobby?", 'question_value': "Rugby"},
{ 'id': 3, 'question_name': "What is your name?", 'question_value': "Peter"},
{ 'id': 4, 'question_name': "What is your hobby?", 'question_value': "Tennis"}
]
```

Write a function that converts that Array into this OUTPUT object:

```
{
"What is your name?": [{"id": 1, "value": "Jack" }, {"id": 3, "value": "Peter" }],
"What is your hobby?": [{"id": 2, "value": "Rugby"}, {"id": 4, "value": "Tennis"}]
}
```

I already have some like this:

```js
const formatter = (o) => {
 const newObject = Object.keys(o).reduce(elm =>
  ({
    "What is your name?": [{'id': elm, 'value': elm}],
    "What is your hobby" : [{'id': elm, 'value': elm}],
  })
 )
 return newObject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `reduce`

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, question_name: "What is your name?", question_value: "Jack" },
  { id: 2, question_name: "What is your hobby?", question_value: "Rugby" },
  { id: 3, question_name: "What is your name?", question_value: "Peter" },
  { id: 4, question_name: "What is your hobby?", question_value: "Tennis" },
]

const res = data.reduce((acc, { id, question_name, question_value: value }) => {
  if (acc[question_name]) {
    acc[question_name].push({ id, value })
  } else {
    acc[question_name] = [{ id, value }]
  }
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

---

#### Reference

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)